# For Disaster Recover, how much faster is it in practice to failover an Aurora Global database vs promote an RDS read replica?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, disaster-recovery

From reading the docs, it's not clear if Aurora Global Database has a lower RTO vs promoting an RDS read replica.  Does anyone know if there is a difference?

AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-global-database-disaster-recovery.html#aurora-global-database-failover.managed-unplanned) say: "For an Aurora Global Database, RTO can be in the order of minutes."

For promoting RDS read replica, RDS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html) say "The promotion process takes a few minutes to complete. When you promote a read replica, replication is stopped and the read replica is rebooted. When the reboot is complete, the read replica is available as a new DB instance."

Answer (score 0):

Both promoting read replica (with in the same region)  and Aurora Global Databases failover takes few minutes, both have different use cases/purpose.

Global database provides regional level failover protection (Example: Failover from US to UK)  compare to read replica that you referred is AZ level (which are with in 60 mile range)

Also, Global database provides low-latency local reads in different Region